# Count tuples in array that are equal to same value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, python-imageio

I have a NumPy array of shape `(100,100,3)` (an RGB image). I want to compare all 3-eleemnt tuples contained in the array for equality to produce array of booleans of shape `(100,100)`.

Expected usage:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [(1,2,3), (2,2,2), (1,2,3), ... ],
    [(0,2,3), (2,2,2), (1,2,3), ... ],
    ...
])
bools = np.some_operation(arr, (1,2,3)
print(bools)
assert(bools == np.array([
    [True,  False, True, ...],
    [False, False, True, ...],
    ...
])
```

I would like to avoid iterating over the whole array in Python code, since scalar access is not very fast in NumPy.

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = np.array([
    [(1,2,3), (2,2,2), (1,2,3) ],
    [(0,2,3), (2,2,2), (1,2,3) ]
])

target = (1,2,3)

result = np.all(arr==target,axis=2)
print(result)
```

am I missing something?

Comment: simple and elegant! `np.all(bool_mask, axis)` also works if you want to compare the pixels of two different images (i.e. two different `(100,100,3)` ndarrays, in this example)